# How do i find the namespace i need for aws using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am looking all over for a list of the namespaces available for elasticbeanstalk. I am using boto3 to change application >> environment >> Software configuration settings to change some environment properties.

But i am looking for a list of namespaces that i can refer to.

Comment: What are you looking for that isn't covered by the official Boto3 documentation? Specifically the list of available services here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html and the documentation detailing each of those services

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of the namespaces"?

Comment: Never got an answer, but found out on my own the documentation is here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html